# SHACL closed shape with superclass inheritance

Tags: shacl

For example in Java, I can close off a class by declaring it as final.
It will still inherit from its superclass, however:

```java
public abstract class Super {
    final boolean test = true;
}
```

```java
public final class Sub extends Super
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(new Sub().test);}
}
```

However in SHACL this does not seem to work:

```
@prefix : <http://test.ex/>.                          
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>.
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>.    
@prefix sh:<http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#>.

:Super a owl:Class.
:Sub a owl:Class;
    rdfs:subClassOf :Super.

:Sub1 a :Sub;
    :exampleProperty :TestObject.

:SuperShape a sh:NodeShape;
    sh:targetClass :Super;
    sh:property [sh:path :exampleProperty].   

:SubShape a sh:NodeShape;
    sh:targetClass :Sub;
    sh:ignoredProperties ( rdf:type );   
    sh:closed true.
```

```
 pyshacl -s test.ttl test.ttl
Validation Report
Conforms: False
Results (1):
Constraint Violation in ClosedConstraintComponent (http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#ClosedConstraintComponent):
    Severity: sh:Violation
    Source Shape: :SubShape
    Focus Node: :Sub1
    Value Node: :TestObject
    Result Path: :exampleProperty
    Message: Node :Sub1 is closed. It cannot have value: :TestObject
```

Is there any way to use closed shapes in SHACL with inheritance?

Answer (score 3):

The official sh:closed does not handle inheritance. But it can be expressed in SHACL-SPARQL which pySHACL seems to understand, so you could use

https://datashapes.org/constraints.html#ClosedByTypesConstraintComponent

for which you'd only need to owl:import the dash shapes graph.